# Retrieve ID of Ecto relationship without preload

Tags: elixir, ecto

Supposing I have two Ecto models (along with their migrations):

```
schema "projects" do
    field :name, :string

    belongs_to :client, MyApp.Client

    timestamps
end

create table(:projects) do
      add :name, :string
      add :client_id, references(:clients)

      timestamps
end

schema "clients" do
    field :name, :string

    has_many :projects, MyApp.Project

   timestamps
end

create table(:clients) do
  add :name, :string

  timestamps
end
```

If I have queried a project model eg.

```
project = Repo.get!(Project, proj.id)
```

As expected, I can't access `project.client.id` because I didn't use a `preload` in the query.

**Whenever I try to access `project.client_id` it returns nil. Surely I should be able to access the foreign key id itself?**

Hopefully the code below illustrates better:

```
client = Repo.insert!(%Client{name: "Test Client"})
proj = Repo.insert!(%Project{name: "Test Project 1", client: client})

project = Repo.get!(Project, proj.id)
assert project.client_id != nil
# ^ This always fails because project.client_id is nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the way you are building `proj` resulting in the `client_id` field never being populated. You could verify this by checking in your database.

You can use [Ecto.Model.build/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Model.html#build/3) to create the project from the client:

```
proj = build(client, :projects, %{name: "Test Project 1"}) |> Repo.insert!
```

Comment: You can just set the field directly too. `build/3` is mostly a convenience around that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the field directly (as someone already mentioned):

```
proj = Repo.insert!(%Project{name: "Test Project 1", client_id: client.id})
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to set the id of the client on the project directly.

```
client = Repo.insert!(%Client{name: "Test Client"})
proj = Repo.insert!(%Project{name: "Test Project 1", client_id: client.id})
```

The association stored in :client is updated automatically when you update the :client_id because Ecto knows that the two are related.